# htaccess mod_rewrite - subfolder type to long urls

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

What I am using currently is,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blahblah/([a-z]+)$ abcd.php?word=$1 [L]
```

So the current output is, site.com/blahblah/word

what I am trying to achieve is, site.com/blahblah/the-word-is-word

Searched all around, couldnt find anything what did this :(

Example :

Orginal url : `site.com/abcd.php?word=Google`

Currently : `site.com/blahblah/Google`

What I am looking for : `site.com/blahblah/the-word-is-Google`

P.S : Capitalization does matter as Google and google is going to be different.

Comment: if you change the [a-z] into (.*) you will be able to redirect all characters so: the-word-is-word will also be passed to the ?word=

Comment: No, you misread the question.
Example, the input is google.

actual url : `site.com/abcd.php?word=google`
what I actually need : `site.com/blahblah/the-word-is-google`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect to blahblah/the-word-is-google.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+abcd\.php\?word=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ blahblah/the-word-is-%1.html? [L,R,NC]

# internal redirect from blahblah/the-word-is-google.html to abcd.php?word=google
RewriteRule ^blahblah/the-word-is-([a-z]+)\.html$ abcd.php?word=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Added the code.

What happens now is, when I go to abcd.php?word=google, it loads for some 5 seconds, and then redirects to the right url, and gives this.

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: works now. :) would be great if you could modify it once more to make the end url extension to .html :) 

Thanks mate :)

Comment: You're most welcome. I edited my answer to have URL extension as `.html`.